# I got no response when I call my cogs commands

Tags: python, discord.py, command

`main.py`

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import discord
import os


class BotClient(discord.Client):
    """Main bot class where all methods and vars are defined"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        load_dotenv()

        self.extensions = ['cogs.music']
        intents = discord.Intents().default()
        intents.members = True

        self.client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)

        for extension in self.extensions:
            try:
                self.client.load_extension(extension)
            except Exception as e:
                exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
                print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))
            print("{} loaded".format(extension))

        try:
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.client = super().run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=True, reconnect=True)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, RuntimeError):
            pass

client = BotClient()
```

`cogs/music.py`

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
    """Music cogs class"""

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(name="test")
    async def test(self, ctx):
        print('executed')
        try:
            await ctx.send("simple command test")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(MusicCog(client))
```

I believe the code is well written since I double-checked and double-checked it, but I still get no replies from the bot in any way when I run the "-test" command

I hope that some of you can understand where I am wrong and give me a hand to make me understand what.

Comment: What does "I got no response" mean? Explain in detail how you use the code, exactly what you expect to see (both in the terminal window and on Discord), and exactly what you do see instead. Also: are you able to make commands work at all, even without the cogs feature? Are you able to verify that, for example, `MusicCog.__init__` runs? As well as the `setup` function?

Comment: I want that when someone writes "-test" the bot replies with "simple command test" Currently when I send the "-test" message the bot does not respond with "simple command test" 
I'm sure the bot is able to read the chat since I tried with the on_message event it sees the messages correctly

Comment: I just checked and `MusicCog.__ init__` and `setup` are called correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours I found a way to fix the problem.

`main.py`

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands

import discord
import os

class BotClient(commands.Bot):
    """Main bot class where all methods and vars are defined"""

    def __init__(self, **options):
        load_dotenv()

        self._cogs = ['cogs.music']
        intents = discord.Intents().all()

        super().__init__(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)

        for extension in self._cogs:
            try:
                super().load_extension(extension)
            except Exception as e:
                exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
                print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))
            print("{} loaded".format(extension))

        super().run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))

client = BotClient()
```

I changed `discord.Client` to `commands.Bot` and adapted the `BotClient` class for a use with `commands.Bot`

The code of the other class (`MusicCog`) has not been changed